# Subset Sum, with backtracking and classes

Tags: c++, algorithm, backtracking

Given a sequence of integers and a number, the program must say if there's any cobination in that sequence that sums the number. For example:

Input: 1 2 3 4 5 # 6
Output: true (because 1+5 = 6, or 2 + 4 = 6, or 1 + 2 + 3 = 6).

It doesn't matter what solution it finds, only if there's a solution.

For input: 1 2 3 4 5 # 100
Output: false. None of the combination of that numbers sums 100.

Now, for input:

```
243 5 35 24 412 325 346 24 243 432 # 1000
```

I'm getting

```
main: malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

When it's suppose to say false.
I must use 3 classes. Solver, solution and candidat.

Solver just calls the backtracking method.
Solution has a possible solution.
Candidat has the indeix of the number of the sequence which is being looked.

I don't understand how to use the integer _lvl of Solution class to move around the different candidates.
Class Solver is correct. The error must be in solution class and candidats.

My question is, how must I use candidats and _lvl to check the possible solutions?
How should I implement the following methods in solution class?:
Acceptable, complet, anotate, desanotate.

Im getting wrong answers and out_of_ranges errors.

```
class solver
{
public:

    solver();

    bool solve(const solution &initial);

    solucio getSolution() const;

private:

    void findASolution();

    bool _found;

    solution _sol;
 };
```

solver.cpp

```
bool solver::solve(const solution &initial)
{
    _found = false;
    _sol = initial;
    findASolution();
    return (_found);
}


void solver::findASolution()
{
    candidat iCan = _sol.inicializateCandidats();
    while ((not iCan.isEnd()) and (!_found))
    {
        if (_sol.acceptable(iCan)) {
            _sol.anotate(iCan);
            if(not _sol.complet()) {
                findASolution();
                if (!_found) {
                    _sol.desanotate(iCan);
                }
            }
            else {
                _found = true;
            }
        }
        iCan.next();
    }
}
```

This class is supposed to be correct. Im having trouble with classes solution and candidat. Class solution have 5 important methods: Acceptable, Complet, inicializateCandidates(), anotate and desanotate.

Acceptable is true if a candidate can be part of the solution.
Complet if a solution is found.
Anotate to save the possible candidates.
Desanotate to remove candidates that no long can be part of the solution.
inicializateCandidates invoces the candidats constructor.

```
    solution();

    solution(const int sequence[], const int &n, const int &sum) {
        _searchedSum = sum;
        _n = n;
        _sum = 0;
        _lvl = 0;
        reserve(); // bad_alloc. Makes space for vectors
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            _sequence[i] = sequence[i];
            _candidates[i] = - 1;
        }

    solution(const solution &o);

    ~solution();

    solution & operator=(const solution &o);

    candidat inicializateCandidats() const {
        return candidat(_n);
    }

    bool acceptable(const candidat &iCan) const {
        return (_sum + _sequence[iCan.actual()] <= _searchedSum);
    }

    bool complet() const {
         return (_sum == _searchedSum);
    }

    void show() const;

    void anotate(const candidat &iCan) {
        _niv++;
        _candidates[_niv] = iCan.actual();
        _sum += _sequence[iCan.actual()];
    }

    void desanotate(const candidat &iCan) {
        _candidates[_niv] = - 1;
        _sum -= _sequence[iCan.actual()];
        _niv--;
   }

private:

    // memory gestion methods
    void solution::reserve() {
        _sequence = new int[_n];
        _candidates = new int[_n];
    }

    int *_sequence; // original sequence
    int *_candidates; // possible subsequence part of solution
    int _n; // size of the array
    int _lvl; // lvl of the tree generated by backtracking
    int _searchedSum; 
    int _sum; // total sum of actual solution
```

And class candidat, which is just a counter. Nothing else.

```
candidat::candidat(const int &n) {
    _size = n;
    _iCan = 0;
}

bool candidat::isEnd() const {
    return (_iCan >= _size);
}

int candidat::actual() const {
    if (esEnd()) {
        throw ("No more candidates");
    }
    return _iCan;
}

void candidat::next() {
    if (esFi()) {
        throw ("No more candidates");
    }
    _iCan++;
}
```

Comment: what is your question? If you need help with errors you should include them in the question.

Comment: "Code is not translated at all, but I'm sure everybody will understands it." sorry, no. It is good practice to write code in english so others can read it

Comment: `// bad_alloc. Makes space for vectors` -- Why don't you just use `std::vector` instead of making up your own vector class?

Comment: is this homework? (nothing wrong about that, I just wonder where the requirement to use 3 classes comes from for something that in principle needs only a couple of lines of code)

Comment: Yes, it's homehowrk. Everything translated, and explained how 3 classes should work. Solver is correct, candidat, probably (not sure) too. Solution definetely not.

Comment: frankly, your code is a bit messed up. It seems like you partly translated the names to english, now you have it mixed. There is `solucio` and `solution`, `candidat` and `candidats`, `inicializateCandidate` and `inicializateCandidat` ....

Comment: I'm really busy, sorry. Everything should be fine now.

Comment: `_sequence` is a pointer but you pretend it is an array. Do you anywhere create an array?

Comment: same goes for `_candidates`. You should use a `std::vector`

Comment: reserve() method, im putting now into the code. I removed it as I thought it was not necessary to show, just that comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution but it does not fit the requirements at all.

In class solver, I create an attribute to save anterior candidate, inicializate at -1.

The constructor of candidat class changes at this way:

```
candidat::candidat(const int &n, const int &ant) {
    _size = n;
    _iCan = ant + 1;
}
```

In solution.h now there is a boolean array to save the candidates that can be part of the solution. _lvl is eliminated.

In solver.cpp, the backtracking changes a little, but it shouldn't be changed.

```
bool solver::solve(const solution &initial) {
    _found = false;
    _ant = -1;
    _sol = initial;
    findASolution();
    return (_found);
}


void solver::findASolution() {
    **candidat iCan = _sol.inicializateCandidats(_ant);**
    while ((not iCan.isEnd()) and (!_found))
    {
        if (_sol.acceptable(iCan)) {
            _sol.anotate(iCan);
            if(not _sol.complet()) {
                **_ant = iCan.actual();**
                findASolution();
                if (!_found) {
                    _sol.desanotate(iCan);
                }
            }
            else {
                _found = true;
            }
        }
        iCan.next();
    }
}
```

Differences remarked.

But this is not the best solution. The correct solution should be using _lvl attribute. The solver class shouldn't know aything about the attributes of solution. Just if it's found or not.